# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5!

In my routes.php file I have the following request to check for all admin requests in the URL:

```
 if (Request::is('admin/*'))
 {
     require __DIR__.'/admin_routes.php';
 }
```

In that case in the corresponding admin_routes.php file it should return the correct controller where I have:

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

     #Admin Dashboard
     Route::get('dashboard', 'Admin\DashboardController@index');
 });
```

I cleared already the route cache (php artisan route:clear) , but I get the  error message: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145 .
Any ideas what could be wrong? Thank you

Comment: Does it work correctly if you move that route group to your main routes file?

Comment: Yes, in the Main Route file it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all your routes in one file, since it is documentation for others aswell. This should be kept as simple as it can be.

Then use [Route Groups](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-groups).

Why would you need to include other files?

Comment: When I put the group routing in one file it works. I thought it is a good idea to keep the Route file  shorter by grouping the related routes in one seperated file. Do you think it is a bad practice?

Comment: I do it all in one file and I don't even use Route::resource. https://github.com/PhotoTresor/server/blob/98e801f8e7f674febfdcee76c46231513c90ffb4/app/routes.php This is a small routes file, I know. But I would do it with a big routes file excactly the same, since you can see all the routes in one blink of an eye. Do the same with your configs. No if-else no includes etc.

Comment: Checkout `php artisan route:list` (l5) or `php artisan routes` (l4) if you fell like loosing the overview of your routes.